# Playing a playlist in Windows store app

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to make an app with windows 8 appstore. I have an app that using fileOpenPicker can select an mp3 file, en play it, and I can also load multiple files and make a playlist. Now how can I play that playlist using the mediaElement?

```
 var openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
            openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.MusicLibrary;
            openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.List;
            openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp3");
           IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> files = await openPicker.PickMultipleFilesAsync();


            if (files != null && files.Count > 0)
            {
               var playlist = new Playlist();

                foreach (StorageFile file in files)
                {
                    playlist.Files.Add(file);
                }

                StorageFile savedFile;
                savedFile = await playlist.SaveAsAsync(KnownFolders.MusicLibrary,"playlist",NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting, PlaylistFormat.WindowsMedia);

                speler.SetSource((await savedFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read)) , ".wpl");
```

This is what I made, but this is one of my first programs, so i'm really searching how to. It doesn't give me any errors it seems like, but it doesn't play either, which I didn't expected, but I thought I could try.

BTW the part AFTER savedFile = await playlist.SaveAsAsync ..... used to be a line where I saved the playlist, and that worked. The program did make the playlist, containing the 2 songs.

Answer (score 0):

Stupid question: Do you use `speler.Play();` afterwards?
This could solve the problem.

Comment: there are is a play button ,but I'll try. But are you able to play playlists, or do I need to do it differently?

edit: Didn't work. I already had a play button, wich worked, but even adding speler.Play(); didn't work